# MySql - Selecting if matching multiple values

Tags: mysql

I have a DB like this:

```
TagSetMap
id | setId | tagId
------------------
1  |  1    |  1
2  |  2    |  2
3  |  3    |  1
4  |  3    |  2
```

I want to retrieve the setId if tagId matches 1 AND 2, which I've been able to do with:

```
SELECT TagSetMap.SetId From TagSetMap 
WHERE TagSetMap.TagId IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY TagSetMap.SetId HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

However, this query doesn't work if I'm trying to get something like tagID = 1, because it will give me back both SetId = 1 and SetId = 3, even with the following query:

```
SELECT TagSetMap.SetId From TagSetMap 
WHERE TagSetMap.TagId IN (1)
GROUP BY TagSetMap.SetId HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Is there a way to modify the query so that it only gives me results that explicitly match my target set (and not supersets)?

Thank you!

Comment: group by both columns

Comment: awful wording in question

Comment: @CPL could  you write out the SQL queries you've tried? It might be easier to understand if formatted nicely.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question - I've modified it and added some queries as well that I'm trying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select setId
from your_table
where tagId in (1,2)
group by setId
having sum(tagId = 1) > 0
or count(distinct tagId) = 2
```